# django post save method causing authentication errors

Tags: django-models

Hi I have a post save signal which saves a user_profile object when a new User object is created:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


def _create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(_create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

However, this is causing me the following problem:

If I create a new user in the admin, all good. If I then try and edit then change the `User` permission to staff status I get a `"Duplicate entry '6' for key 'user_id'"` error. I guess the `UserProfile` object is trying to re-save the object?

How can I avoid this conflict?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this helped a lot:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

Basically I needed to find the `<select>` and the `<option>` I wanted using the `xpath` directly. After that I could just simulate a `click` event:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
     "//select[@id='my_select_id']/option[text()='my_option_text']"
).click()
```

I could have also selected by option index if the text string was unkown:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//select[@id='id_module']/option[2]"
).click()
```

Hope this helps anyone who has a similar problem.